# Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I'm going nuts trying to figure this one out.When I click on my activity it crashes with a NullPointerException.I've tried debugging but I can't get into the activity in question.I've tried removing the Database,still crashed.I tried removing the ListView,still crashed.I tried modifying the database,still crashed.

For some odd reason when I removed the button and its onClickListener on "playbutton",I was able to get into the activity and everything in the activity worked.Can someone help me on why this button is making the app crash before the activity and not on the onclick?

```
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter/com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.PlayAFriend}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2136)
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2174)
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1267)
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.PlayAFriend.onCreate(PlayAFriend.java:54)
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5058)
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
04-05 23:15:15.886: E/AndroidRuntime(11445):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
```

**Activity**

```
package com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter;
import com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.DBAdapter;
import com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;



import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;


import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class PlayAFriend extends Activity{
    DBAdapter DBAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playafriend);

        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        DBAdapter = db.open();

        ListView FriendLV = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        Button playbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
        final TextView friend = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_friends);



        Cursor friendslist = db.GetAllFriends();

        String[] from = new String[] {"FRIENDS"};   // your column/columns here
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.textview_friends};

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        ListAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_items, friendslist, from, to,0);
          FriendLV.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);



          playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String Defender = friend.getText().toString();
                    db.GetFriend(Defender);
                    startActivity(new Intent ("com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.Fightattacker"));
                    db.close();
                }
            });





    }

    }
```

playafriend xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/nfbackground"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/titlebar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nftitlebar" />


        <ListView 
            android:id="@android:id/list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical" >







        </ListView>






</LinearLayout>
```

list_items xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/searchimageview"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/playbutton"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/playbutton" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textview_friends"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />


    </FrameLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add full stacktrace.

Comment: You probably shouldn't have these lines DBAdapter DBAdapter; and DBAdapter = db.open();  Instead db.open(); should suffice. Anyhow, either friend or db are null. Please post logcat with error message.

Comment: Posting your logcat would even better to understand your issue. Also please post your layout file code.

Comment: @Leco just posted my logcat

Comment: Something is null in onCreate, line 54. Which line is line 54?

Comment: @Grishu just posted my logcat

Comment: It looks like playbutton may be the culprit. Is playbutton in the playafriend layout?

Comment: @Leco no it's in a helper layout called list_items

Comment: Have you added `com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.Fightattacker` file  entry in your manifest ?

Comment: @Cranosaur That's why you are getting the error. playbutton is not part of the view and therefore is null.

Comment: @Grishu yes it's in the manifest

Comment: @Leco if that's the case would I have to make a java class for list items and define the button in that class?

Comment: What id have your defined for `ListView` in your layout file ?

Comment: @Cranosaur Not necessarily; I would suggest to just add playbutton to your playafriend layout.

Comment: @Leco I can't since it's a listview layout and I can't add child views in a ListView

Comment: @Grishu FriendLV is the ListView ID

Comment: Is the playbutton specific to a list item? You can still add it to your layout and manage code according to your application logic. I would have to see what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: At the very least I'd say we've answered your null pointer question.

Comment: If your `ListView` is inside your layout file then your should have defined its id as `@android:id/list` and you should access it in your java file by intializing it as `ListView FriendLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);`. So try out that way.

Comment: @Leco I added the button to the playafriend xml and I got a unsupported Exception but yes thank you very much you did aswer my null point exception question

Comment: Can you post the playafriend layout and the list_items layout?

Comment: Is your issue resolved or not ?

Comment: @Leco just posted it up

Comment: @Grishu working on it

Comment: Off the top of my head, here are my recommendations: make your activity a ListActivity; do what Grishu said: ListView FriendLV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); add a  <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty" /> to your playafriend layout. Add the playbutton to your playafriend layout under linear layout (delete it from list_items layout); add an OnItemClickListener to your list and add code there to manage clicking an item list (so you may not need the playbutton for this). If you want the playbutton to be in every list item then I suggest you google for clickable list items.

Comment: @Leco thank you very much this will help me alot I don't have a null point no more but the button isn't working I'm gonna do what you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
 public class Test extends Activity{
        DBAdapter DBAdapter;
        ListView FriendLV;
        Button playbutton;
        final TextView friend;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playafriend);
        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open();
        Cursor friendslist = db.GetAllFriends();
         if(friendslist.getCount()!=0){
             FriendLV = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
             playbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
             friend = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_friends);
             String[] from = new String[] {"FRIENDS"};   // your column/columns here
                int[] to = new int[] {R.id.textview_friends};

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                ListAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_items, friendslist, from, to,0);
                  FriendLV.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
                  playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            String Defender = friend.getText().toString();
                            db.GetFriend(Defender);
                            startActivity(new Intent ("com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.Fightattacker"));
                            db.close();
                        }
                    }); 
         }
    }

    }
```

if you are getting any problem then let me know.

Comment: my nullpoint is solved but I tried this code the button doesn't work I'm just gonna have to take a different approach on this or make a OnItemCLickListener instead and ditch the playbutton.

Comment: No it didn't make a difference this playbutton is show only no onclick to them except for the one I have below the list

Comment: Actually what problem you have to face?

Comment: The title of this question was about a Null point exception I couldn't figure out but from the coments on the question the null point was solved just that now I don't have a button to use on this listview setup I have since that was causing the nullpoint.

Comment: In your listview if each row contain button then you have to create custom Adapter in android.like this way.http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/03/26/dynamic-listview-in-android/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27682/discussion-between-harshid-and-cranosaur)

Answer (score 0):

your Activity should extend ListActivity if using listview